# m2eclipse strange behaviour when using version ranges

Tags: eclipse, maven, version, m2eclipse, range

I have set up a Maven respotory with Nexus on a server.  I have deployed various project artefacts and third party libraries to this repository.

Now I'm trying to use this repository in my eclipse IDE with the m2eclipse plugin.
The idea is that I should just be able to check out a project, enable the Maven dependency management option and it should download all it dependency from the remote repository.

This seems to work when I use specific versions for dependencies, but when I try to use version ranges it will fail, saying missing artefacts.

Here's the strange thing.....if I check out the projects parent POM and enable the dependency management on the parent project, it will download it's dependencies and then child parent also gets resolved. 
I sure I shouldn't have to do this, you should be able to check out any project and it's dependency heirarcy should get resolved automatically.  Which IS the case when I don't use version ranges.

Has anyone else had this problem?  I feel lilke I'm missing a step in my setup somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building the project with command line maven? m2eclipse has it's quirks, so removing it from the equation will tell you if it's an m2eclipse problem or a maven problem.

If building manually with maven works, then it's probably an m2eclipse issue. I would try moving to Eclipse Indigo as it has m2eclipse built in (as well as over a year of development work since the last version of the old m2eclipse). Using the newest version might eliminate any bugs.

If building manually doesn't work, then you're probably doing something incorrect in your pom files or your project structure. In this case, please post some of your poms and your project structure.